# Build image and push to docker hub using github-action

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, docker-registry

Since the FROM syntax in dockerfile doesnt support a github repo link.

There are few Dockerfiles in github repo.

How could I use github action to build them and push to docker-registry once per day?

Comment: Did you try using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images 
It has a `file` option where you can specify the path to a Dockerfile
And if you want to run your action every day, maybe you can try using scheduled events to trigger your workflow.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this example:

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
```